Proof the tangent line pass through the origin
Suppose that the function $f(x)$ is continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $0<a<b$ if $f(a) = ka$, $f(b)=kb$ for some k, show that there exists c in $(a,b)$ such that the tangent line of $y = f(x)$ at $c$ passes through the origin?
Here is my try:
Since $f(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$,
By Mean Value Theorem,
It exists , $c \in (a, b)$ , such that
$f'(c) = \dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} = \dfrac{kb-ka}{b-a} = k$
The equation of the tangent line at $x=c$ is
$y=f(c)+f'(c)(x-c)=f(c)+k(x-c)$
For the tangent line passes through the origin $(0,0)$,
$0-f(c) = k(0-c) => f(c)=kc$
Thus,
It exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that the tangent line passes through the origin.
I'm not sure if this method of proof is valid because I directly substituted
$x=0$ and $y=0$ without explaining why the tangent line passes through the origin.
Are there any better ways to proof this question?

The equation of tangent at $x=c$ may not be the tangent passing through the origin. You cannot substitute it directly.

The tangent line of $f(x)$ at $c$ is $$y=f'(c)(x-c)+f(c).$$  If you wan to this line through the origin, it should let $f(c)-cf'(c)=0$. So you should be choose some $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=cf'(c)$. It is easy to see that$f(x)-xf'(x)$ is just  the numerator of $\left(\frac{f(x}{x})\right)'$.

Good start. But in paragraph 4 (the one that begins “for the tangent line...”) you assumed the fact you wanted to prove.

Let
$$F(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x},\quad x\in[a,b],$$
then $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$
with $$F(a)=F(b)=k.$$
So there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $$F'(c)=\frac{cf'(c)-f(c)}{c^2}=0.$$
Hence $f(c)=cf'(c)$.
You can check that the tangent line at $(c,f(c))$ is through the origin.
The tangent line at $(c,f(c))$ is
$$y=f'(c)(x-c)+f(c)=f'(c)x.$$
